# how to rewrite python dicts to get default values

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to rewrite Python's dictionary access mechanism "**getitem**" to be able to return default values.

The functionality I am looking for is something like

```
a = dict()
a.setdefault_value(None)
print a[100] #this would return none
```

any hints ?

Thanks

Comment: Another possibility is to use `a.get(100, None)`

Comment: yes, I know that one thanks. But it is just ugly to have that all over my code.

Comment: Do you want it to set the missing key to None, or simply return None instead of raising a KeyError?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is already a [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = defaultdict(lambda:None)
print a[100]
```

Comment: Your lambda should be `lambda: None`, otherwise you get `TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`.

Comment: @bukzor, Steven: You are right, I probably fixed it while you were typing.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [defaultdict built-in](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) starting with Python 2.6. The constructor takes a function which will be called when a value is not found. This gives more flexibility than simply returning None.

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = defaultdict(lambda: None)
print a[100] #gives None
```

The `lambda` is just a quick way to define a one-line function with no name. This code is equivalent:

```
def nonegetter():
    return None

a = defaultdict(nonegetter)
print a[100] #gives None
```

This is a very useful pattern which gives you a hash showing the count of each unique object. Using a normal dict, you would need special cases to avoid KeyError.

```
counts = defaultdict(int)
for obj in mylist:
   counts[obj] += 1
```

Comment: and how could I avoid using defaultdict ??

Comment: @webDevelSouth: Why would you want to avoid using defaultdict?

Comment: I'm guessing he's using this as a stepping stone into python OOP. I've put this in a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

use a `defaultdict` (http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
import collections
a = collections.defaultdict(lambda:None)
```

where the argument to the `defaultdict` constructor is a function which returns the default value.

Note that if you access an unset entry, it actually sets it to the default:

```
>>> print a[100]
None
>>> a
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x38faf0>, {100: None})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to not use the defaultdict builtin, you need to define your own subclass of dict, like so:

```
class MyDefaultDict(dict):
    def setdefault_value(self, default):
        self.__default = default
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except IndexError:
            return self.__default
```

Comment: and I guess I could do import MyclassDefaultDict as dict at the top of the script and then I could MyclassDefaultDict as "dict" - am I right ??

Comment: Well, you could, but shouldn't. For one thing, it still won't make it happen for dicts that you defined using curly braces. `{"foo": 1}` is still a Python `dict` even if you have redefined `dict` to be some other class. For another, if whoever maintains your code (including yourself in six months) sees `dict` they're going to assume it's the regular Python dict type.

Answer (score 0):

i wasnt aware of `defaultdict`, and thats probably the best way to go.  if you are opposed for some reason ive written small wrapper function for this purpose in the past.  Has slightly different functionality that may or may not be better for you.

```
def makeDictGet(d, defaultVal):
    return lambda key: d[key] if key in dict else defaultVal
```

And using it...

```
>>> d1 = {'a':1,'b':2}
>>> d1Get = makeDictGet(d1, 0)
>>> d1Get('a')
1
>>> d1Get(5)
0
>>> d1['newAddition'] = 'justAddedThisOne'    #changing dict after the fact is fine
>>> d1Get('newAddition')
'justAddedThisOne'
>>> del d1['a']
>>> d1Get('a')
0
>>> d1GetDefaultNone = makeDictGet(d1, None)   #having more than one such function is fine
>>> print d1GetDefaultNone('notpresent')
None
>>> d1Get('notpresent')
0
>>> f = makeDictGet({'k1':'val1','pi':3.14,'e':2.718},False) #just put new dict as arg if youre ok with being unable to change it or access directly
>>> f('e')
2.718
>>> f('bad')
False
```